# Inheriting from "str" in Python 2.7 and Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, python-2.7, inheritance

I'm porting some older code from python 2.7 to python 3, and I'm trying to figure out how inherinting from str works in both versions. Here is some of the code.

```py
class OtoString(str):
    def __init__(self, p_string):
        str.__init__(self, p_string)


    def is_url(self):
        if self.startswith("http://") or self.startswith("https://"):
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(OtoString("https://stackoverflow.com").is_url())
```

Running this in Python 2.7 works just fine, but when I run this code in Python 3.7 I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

It would be helpful if someone could explain how exactly inheriting from str works, what this line does,

```py
str.__init__(self, p_string)
```

why this doesn't work in Python 3 and how I could make it work.

Comment: @StardustGogeta: That's the wrong way to go; that calls the no-op `__init__` of `str` on `p_string`; it doesn't do anything meaningful to the `OtoString` instance.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oops, you're right. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Minor side-note: `is_url` can be dramatically simplified; `str.startswith` can accept a `tuple` of `str`s so it returns `True` if it starts with any of them, and since it returns `True`/`False` anyway, you can just return the result of the call, rather than testing it, then explicitly returning `True`/`False` (on Python 2, this will provide a mild performance boost, as `True`/`False` are not keywords, but values loaded at runtime from the builtin namespace, which usually means a pair of `dict` lookups). The body of the function can simplify to `return self.startswith(("http://", "https://"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` is an immutable type, and like all immutable types, should perform both construction and initialization [in `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), not [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__). The correct code (that should work on both Python 2 and Python 3) to replace `__init__` would be:

```
def __new__(cls, p_string):
    return str.__new__(cls, p_string)
```

Note that it receives a class object, not an existing instance, and it returns the result of calling `__new__` on the superclass (because `__new__` actually *makes* the new object, it doesn't just initialize one handed to it like `__init__` does).

In this particular case, you should just omit the definition of `__init__`/`__new__` entirely (you'll inherit `str`'s version automatically). But if you need to do additional work (e.g. compute some normalized version of `p_string` before final construction), the `__new__` above is the correct pattern.

Also, to avoid bloating the memory use of your class, I suggest adding:

```
__slots__ = ()
```

as the first line inside your class body; that will avoid making room for an unused `__dict__` and `__weakref__`, keeping your behavior and overhead much closer to that of `str` (on my 64 bit Python 3.6, it reduces the per instance memory overhead, above the cost of the string data itself, from 217 bytes to 81 bytes). Final version would be just:

```
class OtoString(str): 
    __slots__ = () 

    def is_url(self): 
        return self.startswith(("http://", "https://"))
```

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is called after the object is constructed. `str` is immutable, so you cannot modify the value in constructor. The construction must take place in `__new__`, which is class method, so that's why the first parameter is `cls` and not `self`:

```
class OtoString(str):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        return str.__new__(cls, *args, **kw)

    def is_url(self):
        if self.startswith("http://") or self.startswith("https://"):
            return True
        else:
            return False

print(OtoString("https://stackoverflow.com").is_url())
```

Prints:

```
True
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
class OtoString(str):
    def __init__(self,p_string):
        str.__init__(self)
        self.p_string=p_string
    def is_url(self):
        if self.p_string.startswith('https://') or self.p_string.startswith('http://'):
            return True
        return False
```

it works on my computer.

---

this line

```
str.__init__(self, p_string)
```

should be `str.__init__(self)` in python3.x, and it
actually inherits str's **init**. `class OtoString(str)`inherits all functions(including **init**) in str.

Comment: This ends up storing two copies of `p_string`'s value (one true `str` as the attribute, one copy as the value `OtoString` stores in the underlying `str`'s data structure). The `p_string` attribute would be mutable, so you could end up with it displaying one value, while processing another value in `is_url`. This is not the way to go.